# How do I spawn a TNT on someone in Minecraft Bedrock Edition 1.20?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really want to try to spawn a TNT on someone, but I can't figure it out.

How do I spawn a TNT on someone in *Minecraft Bedrock Edition* 1.20?